# No sound from mic in conferencing software (skype, teams, telegram)

Tags: pulseaudio

I use Beyerdynamics Fox USB mic 24/96.
I can successfully record audio with `arecord`, I can see that sound is registered in software settings, I see the mic in all software, but I can't get any sound in conferencing software.

How do I troubleshoot further?

Answer (score 3):

Tell your system, where you mic is. For this I use `pavucontrol`, which is a gui frontend for pulse audio. (`sudo apt install pavucontrol`).

First set the Port:
[image]

And check the configuration: (You might have different entries...)

[image]

Comment: configuration seems fine. In the input devices tab it shows my mic as "analog input"

Comment: When you talk into it, does the "vu-meter" flicker? Maybe you could share the output of `pactl list short sinks` bei copying the answer into your question...